# Clio I indicator control non-functional

Tags: electrical, renault, indicators, clio

- Model: 1997 Renault Clio RL Panache

The hazard lights are functional and I've changed the fuse (to the on-board spare) for the indicators, but still the control stick for the indicators has no effect, with the engine either on or off, and ignition on or off. All other electrical systems seems to be in order.

What is my next step?!

Comment: Indicator lights for either side show nothing? Or does it light and not blink (click)?

Comment: @Paulster2: No click, no dashboard light, no external light activity. Either side. (And I wanna emphasise that the hazard light works normally for all those factors.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it is occurring on both sides with the same result, your problem lies with the switch on the column. There is an outside chance that the wiring harness connection which attaches to the switch might need reseated, so you could attempt that as well.

Comment: Mm.. probably best I don't try to take apart the steering column myself :/

Comment: FWIW I never did attempt this, and no longer own the car.